# How to generate an R package manual

Tags: r, documentation

I am wondering how package manuals like this are generated:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/knitr.pdf

I have tried to follow steps in this page:

[http://ase-research.org/R/](https://web.archive.org/web/20150104035800/http://ase-research.org/R)

which mentions a function `manual(pkg)`, but does not seem to exist.

Comment: Related questions: [How do you write your package documentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3086081/602276) and [How to develop a package in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7297458/602276)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy. Just run:

```
R CMD Rd2pdf <Package directory>
```

Comment: which is what the second link in the question says.

Comment: yeah, it says `manual` is a wrapper of `R CMD Rd2pdf`. I just read the code snippets and didn't look at the text.